# How to iteratively insert values into a df?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'line amount#1': [0.21, 0.13, 0.1], 'line amount#2': [0.0, 0.05, .05], 'line amount#3': [0.5, 0.18, .05]}
dffinalselection= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dffinalselection
```

I'm inserting a lot of values from a df into a df with a body with very similar outlines. I want to insertwhich look very similar:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'TaxSub4':"""
----similar data----- 
          <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">"""+ dffinalselection['line amount#1'] +"""----similar data----- """,
    'TaxSub5':"""
----similar data----- 
          <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">"""+ dffinalselection['line amount#2'] +"""----similar data----- """,
    'TaxSub6':"""
----similar data----- 
          <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">"""+ dffinalselection['line amount#3'] +"""----similar data-----"""
})
```

However, I may have 20 values, hereby scattering my Jupyter notebook into an unorganized jungle.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Desired output:
an output where the above goes dynamically and iteratively

Please help!

Comment: You can simply write a *function* to do that. You also does not need to use a `dict`: a simple *`tuple`* works as long as the dataframe in which you insert the values already have named columns. Finally, please do not use `pd.append` and `pd.Dataframe` to add new lines: this is very *inefficient*. You can add the (unnamed tuple-typed) values in a Python list and then create the final dataframe *from the list* with `pd.Dataframe` (and name the columns at this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f-string`s in [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and then set new columns names:

```
def f(x):
    return f"""
    ----similar data----- 
              <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">{x}----similar data----- """
           

df = dffinalselection.applymap(f)

df.columns = ['TaxSub4', 'TaxSub5','TaxSub6']
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! How would you go about inserting multiple columns into the function?

Comment: @Max Do you think `cols =['line amount#1', 'line amount#2']` and then `df = dffinalselection[cols].applymap(f)`?